# PostgreSQL Return Joined Results of Select

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm learning postgresql and was wondering if i can put long selects in stored procedures
like this one supposed to return select from two joined tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.book_list()
RETURNS TABLE (
  id         BIGINT,
  published  DATE,
  category   VARCHAR,
  author     VARCHAR,
  name       VARCHAR
) AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT
    b.id,
    b.published,
    c.name AS category,
    b.author,
    b.name
  FROM
    schemas.book AS b
  JOIN
    schemas.category AS c
  ON
    c.id = b.category_id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Gives error:

```
select * from api.book_list();
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "book_list" line 3 at SQL statement
```

Comment: Cross post with different alias: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31251/postgresql-return-joined-results-of-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
BEGIN
  return query
  SELECT
    b.id,
    b.published,
    c.name AS category,
    b.author,
    b.name
  FROM
    schemas.book AS b
  JOIN
    schemas.category AS c
  ON
    c.id = b.category_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple query like this, I'd use a `VIEW` or an [**SQL function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.book_list()
RETURNS TABLE (
  id         bigint,
  published  date,
  category   varchar,
  author     varchar,
  name       varchar) AS
$func$
  SELECT b.id
        ,b.published
        ,c.name -- AS category -- alias irrelevant and conflicts with OUT param
        ,b.author
        ,b.name
  FROM   schemas.book b
  JOIN   schemas.category c ON c.id = b.category_id
$func$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then you don't need [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING), `BEGIN` or `END` like you do with `plpgsql`.